# Como listar registros con subregistros en mysql y php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Lo que deseo realizar es lo siguiente , tengo las siguientes tablas en el gestor de base de datos mysql

```
Tabla - comentarios
id_foro int (11)
id_comentarios int(11)
id_user_comment int(11)
file_comment text
date_comment
```

---

```
Tabla - respuestas_comentarios
id_respuesta int(11)
id_comentarios int (11)
file_respuesta text
date_respuesta
```

---

```
Tabla - usuarios
id_usuario int(11)
nombre_usuario text
```

---

> Las tres tablas están relacionadas, la tabla usuario con la tabla comentarios y la  tabla repuestas con la tabla comentarios

Lo que deseo es poder cargar todos los comentarios es decir todos los registros de la tabla comentarios con sus respuestas (Con los registros correspondientes de la tabla respuesta).

Hasta el momento eh realizado un query que me trae todos los comentarios con sus respuestas, pero al momento de imprimirlos por pantalla con php se repiten dos veces el mismo comentario con cada respuesta diferente, si el caso es el siguiente, si dicho comentario tiene mas de una respuesta, el comentario se duplica para mostra la segunda este es mi codigo en php mas el query.

Query

```
SELECT com.id_comentarios, com.file_comment, com.date_comment, res.id_respuesta, res.file_response_c, res.file_respuesta 
FROM c_comment_foro com 
LEFT JOIN response_comment_ res ON res.id_comentarios = com.id_comentarios 
WHERE com.id_foro = 1
```

Efectivamente me trae los registros de comentarios  con su respectiva respuesta quedaria algo como asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al momento de querer renderizar los datos con php en el html de la siguiente manera

```
Comentario 
-- Cantidad de respuestas ....
```

> Cuando los comentarios tienen una sola respuesta mi cogído en php que posteriormente pondré, los datos los renderiza muy bien, pero hay un problema, el fallo esta, cuando algún comentario tiene mas de una respuesta, se repite para mostrar la siguiente respuesta algo como así les daré un ejemplo.

Tengo dos comentarios:
* *`comentario 1`* , con el texto *`hola dsdsds`* con una sola respuesta - *`hola como estas`*
* *`comentario 2`*, con el texto *`tengo el siguiente problema ...`* el cual tiene dos respuestas: *`1 - si claro te podemos ayudar`* y 
*`2 - esta es la solucion`*

Y al renderizarlos con php tengo el siguiente problema

```
comentario 1- 

Hola dsdsds
respuestas 
1 - hola como estas


Comentario 2 -

Tengo este  problema ...
respuestas
1 - si claro te podemos ayudar


Comentario 2 -
Tengo este problema
respuestas
2 - esta es la solucion
```

Si ven , detalladamente el comentario dos se repite para mostrar la segunda respuesta, y lo que deseo es que muestre en cada comentario todas sus respuestas de esta manera

```
Comentario 2 -

Tengo este  problema ...
respuestas
1 - si claro te podemos ayudar
2 - esta es la solución
```

Mi código en php es el siguiente.

```
$stmt = $this->con->prepare('SELECT com.id_comentarios,com.file_comment,com.date_comment,res.id_respuesta,res.file_response_c,res.file_respuesta FROM c_comment_foro com LEFT JOIN response_comment_ res ON res.id_comentarios = com.id_comentarios WHERE com.id_foro = 1');
    $stmt->execute();

    if($stmt){
        if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
            while($data = $stmt->fetch()){

                //transferimos el archivo donde se guardan los comentarios a un array
                $file_comment = file($data['file_comment']);
                $text = "";

                //recorremos los archivos el array y lo aguardamos en un variable
                foreach ($file_comment as  $value) {
                        $text = $value;
                }

                //transferimos el archivo donde se guardan las  respuestas de los comentarios a un array
                $file_response = file($data['file_respuesta']);
                $data_response = "";

                //recorremos los archivos el array y lo aguardamos en un variable
                foreach ($file_response as $response_) {
                    $date_response = $response_;
                    echo $response_;
                }

                //imprimimos o renderizamos los datos

                echo '<p> Comentario </p>
                     <p>'.$text.'</p>
                     <div>respuestas</div>
                     <p>'.$date_response.'</p>';

            }
        }else{
            echo "Este foro no tiene comentarios";
        }
    }else{
        echo "error";
    }
```

¿Como podre arreglar ese problema? muchas gracias por la atención.

Comment: Antes de volver a mostrar el $text del comentario, tendrás que compararlo con el $text anterior, o mejor aún, con el ID de comentario si es que tienes uno. Un condicional decide si mostrás el comentario original, o si solo mostras la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

En tu ejemplo estás leyendo el contenido del comentario o su respuesta de un archivo. Para efectos de mi respuesta, vamos a suponer que tus tablas tienen la estructura:

comentario:

```
id_comentario
texto_comentario
```

respuesta:

```
id_respuesta
id_comentario
texto_respuesta
```

Entonces, dentro del bucle almacenas el ID del comentario y sólo escribes el texto de éste si el ID ha cambiado respecto a la iteración anterior:

```
$stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT 
            com.id_comentario,
            com.texto_comentario,
            res.texto_respuesta
       FROM comentario com LEFT JOIN respuesta res ON 
       res.id_comentario = com.id_comentario");
$stmt->execute();

if(!$stmt){
  echo "Se produjo un error";
} else if(stmt->rowCount() === 0) {
  echo "No hay comentarios";
} else {
    $id_comentario=0; // inicializo el ID vigente
    while($data = $stmt->fetch()){
      $new_id = $data['id_comentario'];
      if($new_id !== $id_comentario) { // si no es el mismo comentario
         $id_comentario = $new_id; // actualizo el ID vigente
          echo '<p> Comentario </p>';
          echo '<p>'.$data['texto_comentario'].'</p>';
          echo '<p> Respuestas: </p>';
      }

      $texto_respuesta = $data['texto_respuesta'];
      if($texto_respuesta === null) { // el left join no encontró respuestas
         echo "Este comentario no tiene respuestas";
      } else {
         echo "<p>".$texto_respuesta."</p>";
      }
   }
}
```